# Regular Expression which matches space or nothing

Tags: java, regex

I have JTextPane which colors "int" words blue. Such regexp is wrong because it will also color "print":

```
int + "(\\[\\])*" //To match eg. int[]
```

So I came on idea with such regexp:

```
"\\s" + int + "(\\[\\])*"
```

Its okay but doesnt work if user types int as first in text pane. How to solve this problem? Is there some symbol for NOTHING? So i could make: \s | NOTHING

Comment: try `"\\bint\\S*"` the `\S*` allows for 0 or more non-whitespace characters, so you can match `int()`, `int[]`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just match `int` surrounded by [word boundaries, which are matched by `\b`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds). The pattern:

```
"\\bint\\b"
```

More reading over at [the always-excellent regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an optional space? That would be `\\s?`. Or to allow zero or more spaces: `\\s*`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using this:

```
/\bint\S*/ig
```

Not entirely sure how that translates to Java, but the string portion would look like this:

```
"\\bint\\S*"
```

The regex translates to:

find "int" following a word boundary, capture it and anything else until a whitespace character.

It allows you to match

```
int[]
int()
interesting
int!@#$%^&*()_+~=-
```

etc etc.

If you want to ONLY capture `int[], int()` and the like, the regex would obviously be different.